# Best way to secure application's local files that will be created on user computer during runtime

Tags: c++, windows

The application creates configuration, calibration, and measurement data binary files on the users computer. I want to minimize the possibility of the user editing or deleting them. Besides psychological tricks, is there an actual way of locking the files down, or preparing for the possibility of user tampering/deletion?

Comment: You can't prevent users from modifying files on their own machines. But you *can* calculate and *check* a checksum of the data to *detect* modification.

Comment: @JesperJuhl and what prevents user from modifying checksum as well?

Comment: @SergeyA nothing unless you sign it with some cryptographic key. And then the question becomes "how do you protect the key". The answer to that *may* be hardware, or it may be "you don't". I don't have a good answer to that.

Comment: There is no bullet-proof solution to that unless you are using specialized environment (for example, this would be possible in Android). In PC, the best you could do is to sign the data with the key which would be carefully hidden within app code itself. It is still not bullet proof, and would be subject to the dedicated user extracting it, but makes it if course less likely.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, yeah, it's impossible on the general hardware. But the question is, why user is prevented from owning data their computer generates? :)

Comment: @SergeyA I'm not trying to answer *why* someone would do this, nor whether it's a good idea, nor whether it is ethical to try and prevent users from modifying data on their own machines (I don't think it is). I was merely trying to answer OPs question of "how do I do this". And the only answer I have is "you don't" - at least not without custom hardware the user can't tamper with that holds secret keys.

Comment: Thank you Jesper and Sergey. The purpose would be to prevent against user accidently modifying or deleting critical files if they became curious and wandered into system files.

Comment: Seems the best method is to do the checksum as Jesper suggested and alert the user on opening the application that modification was detected and contact support.

Comment: You can hide the files (unix add a . as the first character). This will help in stopping accidental deletion or editing. Use a checksum to prevent accidental modification by bumbling user. But you can't prevent a determined user (developer).